# $U(n) =$ the smallest strictly positive integer $k$ such that $2^k-1$ is divisible by the first $n$ primes. What are the first values of $U(n)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, exponentiation, divisibility

$U(n) =$ the smallest strictly positive integer $k$ such that $2^k-1$ is divisible by the first $n$ prime numbers (except for the first prime number: $2$).

What are the first values of $U(n)$ up to $n=11$ ?

I've already found the first values of $U(n)$ up to $n=4$ :

- $U(2) = 2$ $(4)$
- $U(3) = 4$ $(16)$
- $U(4) = 12$ $(4096)$

Comment: $U(5) = U(6) = 60$, $U(7) = 120$, $U(8)  = 360$, $U(9) = 3960$, $U(10) = U(11) = 27720$, I think.

Comment: $2$, $12$, $60$, $120$ and $360$ all are superior highly composite numbers. While $4$ and $27720$ are highly composite numbers. $3960$ isn't a highly composite number, but it's close to being one since $3960=360 \times 11$ ($360 \times 7=2520$ is a superior highly composite number). This is absolutely fascinating. But what is the hidden meaning of all this?

Comment: These numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A155747

Comment: Thanks! But why does this sequence has so much similarity with the superior highly composite numbers sequence and the highly composite numbers sequence?